# Closing iPython while script is running

Tags: python, ipython

I closed iPython explicitly when a script was running. The script didn't stop and is still running in the background, creating some output files. How can I stop the script?

Comment: Are you using windows ?

Comment: no . i am on ubuntu.

Comment: On Linux, just `kill` the process (you can find it via `ps` or `top`).

Comment: `ps aux | grep ipython ` ?

Comment: No, since iPython might not be running anymore. Find some Python process instead.

Comment: And when you say 'closed IPython', what exactly do you mean. Were you using IPython notebook, Qt console, or terminal interface?

Comment: I ran the script from IPython Qt console. Then i tried CTRL + C. but it wasn't working. So i closed IPython console. But script is still running.

Answer (score 0):

You can kill the ipython process by this command

```
ps aux | grep ipython | grep -v "grep ipython" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```